# Different ways of running a service on DC/OS

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

Kinda newbie on `DC/OS` so bear with me on this rather trivial question.

I have set up a HA `DC/OS` cluster.

I want to deploy some container services.

What is the difference between running services

a) By selecting the `Services` option on the left pane that prompts you with the following options below

[image]

b) by installing `Marathon` from the catalogue and then running service on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a) will ultimately use the already present Marathon instance, and b) will install a Marathon-on-Marathon instance, which is unnecessary if you just want to run a few containers and/or services.

Comment: Thx. So is there a purpose or a use case for the marathon on marathon option?

Comment: E.g., you can run Marathon per team and easily manage roles, resources reservation, security.